# How can use Cloudinary just on production and use my file storage on development (Using Carrierwave Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave, cloudinary, uploader

I have an application **Rails** deployed on **Heroku**. I'm using the adds-on **Cloudinary** and the gem **Carrierwave** to upload images.

Following the Cloudinary documentation I have could configure the uploading images on Production successfully but in Development, it is also uploading to the cloud. My issue here is that I would like to use the file storage in my local machine instead of upload images to Cloudinary (just upload to Cloudinary in production).

I have tried to fix that using `storage :file if Rails.env == "development"` but didn't work. Any idea to solve it?

My uploader is:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # storage :file if Rails.env == "development"

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  end

  version :card do
    process resize_to_fit: [250, 250]
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also remember not being able to handle this situation in a past project. As we were using AWS S3 we could differentiate assets from deve and prod by storing them in a different bucket, however in Cloudinary this seems to be not possible.

Maybe this setup we used for test environment might help you in your dev environment.

Place this code in `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`

```rb
if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
    config.asset_host = ActionController::Base.asset_host
  end

  ImageUploader

  CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.descendants.each do |klass|
    next if klass.anonymous?
    klass.class_eval do
      # Need to set the storage here otherwise the class
      # overrides it in the uploader definition
      storage :file

      def cache_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/tmp"
      end

      def store_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end
    end
  end
else
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    # Production setup
  end
end
```

Hope this helps you. It worked for us.